# Pykafka - sending messages and receiving acknowledgments asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, pykafka

PyKafka has the limitation that:

> delivery report queue is thread-local: it will only serve reports for messages which were produced from the current thread

I'm trying to write a script where I can asynchronously send messages using one function, and keep receiving acknowledgments via another function.

Here are the functions:

```
def SendRequest(producer):

        count=0        
        while True:
            count += 1
            producer.produce('test msg', partition_key='{}'.format(count))
            if count == 50000:
                  endtime=datetime.datetime.now()
                  print "EndTime : ",endtime
                  print "Done sending all messages.Waiting for response now"
                  return



def GetResponse(producer):

    count_response=0

    while True:

              try:
                  msg, exc = producer.get_delivery_report(block=False)
                  if exc is not None:
                      count_response+=1
                      print 'Failed to deliver msg {}: {}'.format(
                          msg.partition_key, repr(exc))
                  else:
                      print "Count Res :",count_response
                      count_response+=1

              except Queue.Empty:
                  pass

              except Exception,e:
                  print "Unhandled exception : ",e
```

Threading and multiprocessing did not help. These above two functions need to be running asynchronously/in parallel. What approach shall be used here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyKafka producer.get\_delivery\_report throwing Queue.empty when block=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298796/pykafka-producer-get-delivery-report-throwing-queue-empty-when-block-false)

Comment: Actually thats different. Here I'm looking to fetch requests and acknowledgments at the same time. In the example you mentioned, first all requests are being sent,and then the acknowledgments are being read, so its still sequential.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: where I can asynchronously send messages ... and keep receiving acknowledgments

This solution with `asyncio.coroutine` will met your needs.

> **Note: There are a few drawbacks!**
>
> - This `asyncio` code needs at least Python 3.5
> - For every Message, a **new** Task is created

This implements the `class AsyncProduceReport()`:

```
import asyncio
from pykafka import KafkaClient
import queue, datetime

class AsyncProduceReport(object):
    def __init__(self, topic):
        self.client = KafkaClient(hosts='127.0.0.1:9092')
        self.topic = self.client.topics[bytes(topic, encoding='utf-8')]
        self.producer = self.topic.get_producer(delivery_reports=True)
        self._tasks = 0

    # async
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def produce(self, msg, id):
        print("AsyncProduceReport::produce({})".format(id))
        self._tasks += 1
        self.producer.produce(bytes(msg, encoding='utf-8'))

        # await - resume next awaiting task
        result = yield from self.get_delivery_report(id)

        self._tasks -= 1
        # This return values are passed to self.callback(task)
        return id, result

    def get_delivery_report(self, id):
        """
         This part of a Task, runs as long as of receiving the delivery_report
        :param id: ID of Message
        :return: True on Success else False
        """
        print("{}".format('AsyncProduceReport::get_delivery_report({})'.format(id)))

        while True:
            try:
                msg, exc = self.producer.get_delivery_report(block=False)
                return (not exc, exc)

            except queue.Empty:
                # await - resume next awaiting task
                yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

    @staticmethod
    def callback(task):
        """
         Processing Task Results
        :param task: Holds the Return values from self.produce(...)
        :return: None
        """
        try:
            id, result = task.result()
            print("AsyncProduceReport::callback: Msg:{} delivery_report:{}"
                    .format(id, result))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def ensure_futures(self):
        """
         This is the first Task
         Creates a new taks for every Message
        :return: None
        """

        # Create 3 Tasks for this testcase
        for id in range(1, 4):
            # Schedule the execution of self.produce(id): wrap it in a future. 
            # Return a Task object.
            # The task will resumed at the next await
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.produce('test msg {} {}'
                     .format(id, datetime.datetime.now()), id))

            # Add a Result Callback function
            task.add_done_callback(self.callback)

            # await - resume next awaiting task
            # This sleep value could be 0 - Only for this testcase == 5
            # Raising this value, will give more time for waiting tasks
            yield from asyncio.sleep(5)
            # print('Created task {}...'.format(_id))

        # await - all tasks completed
        while self._tasks > 0:
            yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
```

> **Usage**:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = AsyncProduceReport('topic01')        
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(client.ensure_futures())
    loop.close()
    print("{}".format('EXIT main()'))
```

> **Qutput**:
>
> ```
> AsyncProduceReport::produce(1)
> AsyncProduceReport::get_delivery_report(1)
> AsyncProduceReport::produce(2)
> AsyncProduceReport::get_delivery_report(2)
> AsyncProduceReport::callback: Msg:1 delivery_report:(True, None)
> AsyncProduceReport::produce(3)
> AsyncProduceReport::get_delivery_report(3)
> AsyncProduceReport::callback: Msg:2 delivery_report:(True, None)
> AsyncProduceReport::callback: Msg:3 delivery_report:(True, None)
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.5.3 - pykafka:2.7.0***